# Is it possible to determine the number of "standardized" quadratic forms?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, group-actions, quadratic-forms

Given a quadratic form $q$ on $\mathbb R^n$, are there methods to determine the number of "standardized" quadratic forms using the Gauss's square decomposition algorithm ([https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Réduction_de_Gauss](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss)) ?

In general, using this algorithm can lead to several standardized forms. I was wondering if there was a sort of "canonical" representative for the quadratic form  which after a "change of basis" gives all the other ones ?

For instance, on $\mathbb R^4$ for the quadratic form $q(x,y,z,t) = xt - 2yz - yt + xz$, we can quickly give two standardized forms (after using Gauss's square decomposition algorithm).

We obtain the following four independent linear forms :

$f_1 = x - y + z + t$  ;  $f_2 = x - y - z - t$  ;  $f_3 = y + z$  ;  $f_4 = y - z$.

And also :

$f_1 =  x + z + t$  ;  $f_2 = x - z - t$  ;  $f_3 = y + 2z + t$  ;  $f_4 = y - 2z - t$.

Are there references about these kind of questions ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you elaborate on Gauss’ square decomposition algorithm?

Comment: @user633430 Done !